# Sql Dynamic Column for Position of AgentID

Tags: mysql, linq-to-sql

I had Collection Table for Agents

```
Agentid         logintime             AmountReceived

1        2013/10/01 00:10:10         10000
1        2013/10/01 17:23:10         200
1        2013/10/01 00:30:41         3000
2        2013/10/02 05:10:52         1000
3        2013/10/02 09:10:25         2000 
3        2013/10/03 10:10:18         2000
2        2013/10/03 13:10:35         7000
```

I want a query that should display the output as

```
Agentid    Amount  Rank
  1         13200    1
  2         8000     2
  3         4000     3
```

Displaying UI:

```
agentID : 1

Today:   13200 (Today amount yesturady amount should be place in this month)
Month:   Need to display month total amount(30 days amount last month amount in this year)
Year :   Need to display year total amount(12 months amount)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Agentid,SUM(AmountReceived) as Amount,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS Rank
FROM TableName,(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
GROUP BY AgentID
ORDER BY SUM(AmountReceived) DESC
```

Result:

```
AGENTID  AMOUNT     RANK
1        13200      1
2        8000       2
3        4000       3
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65c40/4).

**EDIT:**

For year-wise and month-wise result:

```
SELECT Agentid,year(logintime) as Year,monthname(logintime) as Month,SUM(AmountReceived) as Amount,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS Rank
FROM TableName,(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
GROUP BY AgentID,year(logintime),monthname(logintime)
ORDER BY SUM(AmountReceived) DESC
```

Result:

```
AGENTID   YEAR   MONTH      AMOUNT  RANK
1         2013   October    13200   1
2         2013   October    8000    2
3         2013   October    4000    3
```

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65c40/11).

Comment: OP also sounds like expecting `month`, and `year` wise totals.

Comment: Cool but I think you got mis conveyed. total group by each year, last month, this day. OP asked like that

Comment: i need to display total amount of month and year also in UI

Comment: @Ravinder: If we use `GROUP BY` day, we won't get the OP's desired output. [See this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65c40/13).

Comment: Yes. Possible other solution you may suggest with a workaround to include all. Otherwise OP should depend on his client app to sort the things. Actually, I feel OP has posted 2 questions in one and we can't combine them into one answer.

Comment: @sandeep: We can't find the total amount of year when we `GROUP BY` month.

Comment: hi all can any one help to convert above query lina-to sql(lamba expressions) because i need to develop webapi service for this ...

Comment: hi Raging Bull,could you please help me for this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421550/convert-mysql-query-in-entity-querylambda-expression